# is it possible to overload a string as a vector of char elements?

Tags: c++

I have a class which acts on a list of elements, like so:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    ...
};
```

I need to implement certain methods, that work both on a `vector<T>` and a `string` - which is what most of the users would be using when they initialise an object as `MyClass<char>()`.

Due to this I am being forced to follow this overloading pattern:

```
void method(vector<T> elements){

}

void method(string elements){
    method(convertStringToVector(elements));
}
```

where `vector<char> convertStringToVector(string str)` is defined as expected.

That is, for each class method I am being forced to add an additional method that overloads for `string`. I find it an unnecessary overhead, and also sometimes forget to add it.

I will be doing exactly the same things on the string as I would do on the corresponding vector - same methods will be called in both cases, same iteration, etc. Thus, I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this, without adding much code overhead. Is there?

Comment: What does it mean "very similar"? If syntactically there is a difference, you have to implement two functions. If they are the same, (say, `.size()`) then you can implement one.

Comment: Do you want `std::span`?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis By very similar, I mean that I will be doing exactly the same things on the string as I would do on a vector - same methods will be called in both cases. I have clarified my question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry I never knew about it. If it allows O(1) element access, iteration, and basic `.size()` operations, and it can overload with a string in a cleaner way, then it sure is a good thing! I will try test it out.

Comment: _I need to implement certain methods, that work both on..._ That's exactly why we write algorithms in terms of iterators.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry I can't get it to compile. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/m1hc0i)

Comment: @DanielLangr how would I write my iterator though? Wouldn't the type of iterators in case of string and vector be different?

Comment: @GaurangTandon If GCC doesn't support `span` yet, you can make a custom span-like class.

Comment: @GaurangTandon You have something that _acts_ on a list=range of elements. That range can be defined generally by iterators (of a different type). The point is to write your algorithm=action in terms of iterators. Look at how [C++ algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) are defined, they work with iterators, not containers. A particular implementation will depend on what you action looks like (we don't know).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is to implement your method as a template, whose parameter is not restricted to be either `string` or `vector<char>`.

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    template <class C>
    void method(C container);
};
```

This solves your problem because one implementation is enough for both cases:

```
template <typename T>
template <class C>
void MyClass<T>::method(C container)
{
    std::cout << "Container has size " << container.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "First element is " << container[0] << '\n';
}
```

However, this will work on any container. It's not clear whether this is good (code is generic) or bad (code allows undesirable instantiations).

Imagine what happens when people try to send `vector<int>` instead of `vector<char>` to your method by mistake. Because you didn't build your code for this case, it will either display obscure compilation errors, or generate code which silently does the wrong thing at runtime.

Comment: You can prevent undesirable instantiations with a bit of SFINAE on the container's `value_type`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class to use as parameter to your methods, which accepts both `std::vector<char>` and `std::string`:

```cpp
class MyString
{
public:
  MyString(const std::vector<char>& v) : vector(v) {}
  MyString(std::vector<char>&& v) : vector(std::move(v)) {}
  MyString(const std::string& s) : vector(convertStringToVector(s)) {}

  std::vector<char> vector;
};

void method(MyString elements)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `convertStringToVector` as method of your class like this:

`vector<T> convertStringToVector(string str)`

or a separate template function, if you need it independently for other classes.

Also I would pass the argument as reference `const string &str`.

If any template parameter you use is incompatible with the algorithm, the compiler will tell you about.

For those special cases you can still write a template specialization like this:

```
template<>
vector<SPECIALTYPE> convertStringToVector<SPECIALTYPE>(string str)
{
   ...
}
```

and implement different code for such `SPECIALTYPE`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this is exactly what I am doing right now, and wanted a way which was cleaner than this.